# R plots are connecting different trend lines, how do I stop it?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, r-caret

Here is some code to reproduce the effect I'm seeing:

```
library(datasets)
library(caret)


utils.plot.summaryMetrics <- function(path, model) {
    # multiclass metrics
    for (stat in colnames(model$results)) {
        if (!all(is.na(model$results[,stat]))) {
            filepath <- sprintf("%s/%s.pdf", path, stat)
            message(sprintf("Saving %s.pdf graph to trial", stat))
            ggplot(model, metric=stat) + geom_line(colour="cornflowerblue") + geom_point(colour="coral")
            ggsave(filepath)
        } else {
            message(sprintf("Stat column has all null values: %s", stat))
        }
    }
}

result <- train(Species ~., data = iris, method='nnet')

utils.plot.summaryMetrics(".", result)

# produces graphs where the different plot lines are interconnected.
# example -> http://i.imgur.com/Fx0l2Wq.png
# this should be 3 parallel lines, but instead a box has been drawn connecting 
# points. how do get rid of the box lines?
```

And here's an example of the image it outputs where the parallel lines are interconnected creating a box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, being new to R I'm admittedly cargo culting a bit. It seems the culprit is the geom_line(..) func. I tried adding a group argument, but no go.

In the end, removing those two produces graphs without interconnected lines.

While not a perfect answer, it's "good enough" for now. But I'll happily flip the selected answer to whomever can provide a more robust explanation.